# Fast growing trees for shade & fruits in Sri Ganganagar, Rajasthan

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations

I am presently in [Sri Ganganagar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Ganganagar), [Rajasthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajasthan) bordering [Punjab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_India) & [Rajasthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajasthan). I want to grow a miniature forest in my backyard, I request to suggest fast growing trees for shade & fruits. I have moderate water supply.